# I have an 07 Honda Accord 6 cylinder with a brake issue... Maybe something else too

Tags: honda, noise, accord

I do a lot of the work on my car, having had too many bad experiences at shops. So I had a loud whining noise which sounded like my brake wear indicator, I replace the rotors and pads because I had wanted to do the rotors any ways, and after replacing those parts, the sound was still there. Now I was driving around the neighborhood to test things out, heard a light crunch when I hit a bump and applied the brakes, I let off and applied the brakes again, no sound this time but a light scraping sound still came from the car but not the wear indicator (seeming) sound.

Now my front passenger tire is the one making that said sound which now has started to come back on my way home from work today any bumps would be loud, and sounded like my shock on the passenger side was shot?

Get home and hop out of the car, passenger side brake is smoking slightly but stopped within the time it takes to turn off and get out of a car.

Is my piston stuck? Do I need to bleed my brakes? I'm an amateur at best and don't claim to know a lot but I want and need to get this fixed up as its my only ride and daily driver at the moment..

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is difficult to diagnose sounds from text. Wheel bearings can make a growling sound when they are going bad (it sounds like you have a snow tire on there). Any way you can record the sound? Have you put the car on jack-stands and rotated the wheel to isolate the location of the noise? While in the air, you should not be able to wiggle the wheel. Here is a good video on [How To Tell If You Need A Wheel Bearing Replaced](https://youtu.be/p2nMCRaCspo).

Comment: Hey thanks Charlie!

I listened to a LOT of videos and without a doubt I can say it isn't that noise. The noise is closer to the sound of the Brake Warning pin scraping along the rotor. This low growling sound is not what I am experiencing while driving. I am at work for now, however I will upload the sound file I have, and if possible I'll try and make a video.

Comment: OK. Good job. That is a start to narrowing it down.

Comment: Is there a dust shield of some kind on your car, behind the caliper or disk? Maybe that is bent and touching the rotor or rim.

Comment: If the caliper was stuck, it would be hot to the touch and more than likely the wheel would be hot too. Oil residue from the new rotors is the more likely explanation, especially if the caliper piston went in easy and the guide pins were working correctly.

Comment: I tried bending the dust shield before as well thinking much the same. And it went it easy enough using the brake pad and c-clamp method.. Wheel was pretty hot but it's also Texas and 103 today. Haven't had the time just yet to upload a video but I will try by then end of today. I kinda thought maybe the new brakes where to blame partially for the smoke I got the cheapest pads as my current situation doesn't leave me much money.

Comment: Well the wheel and calipers are getting pretty hot though no more smoking . I did use a lube AutoZone gave me for moving parts... Video last week of me before new rotors and pads. Still making same but quieter scraping sound.. https://youtu.be/1l6VpE7demA